# Problems swiping right with UISwipeGestureRecognizer (Swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

After watching this quick [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WD8T7ipVOZM), I set up very similar `swipeLeft` and `swipeRight` methods. I've ensured that the two gesture recognizers I added to the scene were set to "left" and "right" respectively, and verified that my `@IBActions` were linked to the correct recognizers.

For some reason, **the swipe left recognizer is working but the swipe right isn't** (which is even more strange, since most of what I'm reading discusses how the recognizer directions are default right). I've tested this on an iPhone 8 and the simulator (SE + 10).

When I'm using the terms "left" and "right" I'm assuming they mean the direction the swipe is headed (e.g. left = starting from right side and sliding finger to the left).

My methods are as follows:

```
@IBAction func swipeLeft(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print("swiped left")
}

@IBAction func swipeRight(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print("swipe right")
}
```

[image: (R) is the one not working...]

**UPDATE**

Both bubbles to the left of the IBActions (used to connect to the view controller) are filled in. When I click them (tried to get a screenshot, but it goes away) they both show that they're connected (respectively):

```
Main.storyboard -- Swipe Gesture Recognizer (R)
Main.storyboard -- Swipe Gesture Recognizer (L)
```

However, when I right click the recognizers, there's a disparity on their connections. **They both show sent actions for their respective methods, but the (L) has a `Referencing Outlet Collections` while (R) doesn't.**

**After connecting that up, everything is working.** Not sure why it didn't connect originally, but that solved it. Thanks for everyones' help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you dragged it on the view that should listen to the gesture. Check the links pane to see differences between them and link between the right gesture to the view
Maybe the first gesture recognizer disables the second, try to disable the first and see if it helps.. You should set them to forward touches to other recognizers

EDIT: as you said, you should've add a connection to referencing outlets
Glad I could help you (I had this problem at the past) good luck!

Comment: As I said I've reconnected and verified they were linked to the right gesture. I've also adjusted the order in case that mattered. In the demo video though, they didn't have to do anything like that

Comment: Did you checked that they forward touches?

Comment: Aside from the swipe direction, both recognizers are configured the same way. Not sure how to check that they're both forwarding the touches...

Comment: So I switched them both to "left" and the first recognizer (original righty) still isn't working...

Comment: Disable the left so it won't get touches event and then see if the right works

Comment: Can you print in debug the gestureRecognizers property of the view? How many does it have?

Comment: The (R) recognizer didn't have a connection to referencing outlets. Your advice helped me to recognize that. If you want to adjust your answer to reflect what I wrote in the update, I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks.